# How can I map controller endpoints to actions on F#?

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I am probably missing something here as I am new to F#, however, I need the following:

```ml
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc


[<ApiController>]
[<Route("[controller]")>]
type MyController () =
    inherit ControllerBase()

    
    //[<HttpGet(Name = "Ip")>] doesn't work neither.
    [<HttpGet>]
    [<Route("[controller]/[action]")>]
    member _.Ip() =
        "192.168.199.2"
```

The URL: `https://localhost:5001/my/ip` should return: `192.168.199.2`.

The error message I am getting instead:

```json
{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-389e8d2f6bc3a342a3754b5c5ce7915f-7e6e851c78f47c4f-00","errors":{"id":["The value 'ip' is not valid."]}}
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce what you're seeing. I wrote a vanilla F# class that inherits from `Controller` and exposes `Ip` just the way you do and it works fine. Maybe we need to see more of your code? I assume you're not literally using the string "<controller>" in your URL, right? It should be the name of your actual controller instead.

Comment: @brianberns I've edited the question. In fact, my controller inheriting from ControllerBase.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with ASP.NET Core, but I think the problem is that you have a route set at both the class and member level. These are additive, so the actual URL of your `Ip` action is currently `https://localhost:5001/my/my/ip`.

To fix this, remove the `Route` attribute entirely from the class level, or remove the `[controller]` prefix from your member-level route:

```
[<ApiController>]
[<Route("[controller]")>]   // controller is specified here, so...
type MyController() =
    inherit ControllerBase()

    [<HttpGet>]
    [<Route("[action]")>]   // ...no controller specified here
    member _.Ip() =
        "192.168.199.2"
```