# How do I add action for the homecontroller in f# mvc application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, f#

I'm trying to get started on doing f# mvc projects, and I am doing some sanity checking for myself, to make sure I understand it.
I have generated a scaffolded application, using a downloaded mvc template, by installing a bunch of templates, and then opening a project woth the template:

```
$ dotnet new --install Microsoft.DotNet.Web.ProjectTemplates.5.0::5.0.6
$ dotnet new mvc -lang "F#"
```

Which started a nice looking f# mvc .net core template.
I now have have a `startup.fs` with the following routing conventions:

member this.Configure(app: IApplicationBuilder, env: IWebHostEnvironment) =

```
if (env.IsDevelopment()) then


 app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage() |> ignore
    else
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error") |> ignore
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts() |> ignore

app.UseHttpsRedirection() |> ignore
app.UseStaticFiles() |> ignore

app.UseRouting() |> ignore

app.UseAuthorization() |> ignore

app.UseEndpoints(fun endpoints ->
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name = "default",
        pattern = "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}") |> ignore
    endpoints.MapRazorPages() |> ignore) |> ignore
```

And then I have a homeController that looks like this:

```
type HomeController (logger : ILogger<HomeController>) =
    inherit Controller()

    member this.Index () =
        this.View()

    member this.Privacy () =
        this.View()
```

Now since the routing conventions is governed by the pattern that it is, I was thinking that I could attempt adding a new action here, and get it to serve me some content. So the controller would have this body:

```
member this.Index () =
    this.View()    
member this.newPath() =
    his.Content("Hello Werld")
member this.Privacy () =
    this.View()
```

But When I run the project, and acces the url `https://localhost:5001/newPath`, then no page can be found?

Why is'nt anything displayed? Should'nt the routing conventions "catch" my action here?

And how do I make actions that actually get displayed?

EDIT:

I now noticed that if I use the url `https://localhost:5001/home/Privacy`, then I actually get the `Privacy` action invoked.

This must somehow mean that if the index action is not invoked, then it can't infer itself that it should use the home controller if only the base url is used.

Why is this?

Comment: did you try `https://localhost:5001/newPath/Privacy` ?

Comment: No, `https://localhost:5001/home/Privacy` or `https://localhost:5001/home/newPath` works. My issue now is that I don't understand why the homecontroller is used for the root url, but not if I try to access other actions than index() on home

Comment: that's somewhat a weird behavior, I'm not an expert but try specifying the route in the controller and action [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66375933/how-can-i-map-controller-endpoints-to-actions-on-f)